# Spring controller for multiple tables

Tags: java, spring, rest, controller

We have an endpoint in our controller that takes in data type as a parameter and gathers the appropriate information to return a given table. The JSON format we are returning is standardized, regardless of the data we are returning.

Is it bad practice to have a controller function in this way? Would it be better to have a method for each of these different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get deleted for attracting "opinion based" answers but...

I think it depends on what the consumers of your endpoints want. If they want to pass a parameter rather than call a different endpoint, then you should do what you are currently doing. If they don't care (or you are the consumer), do what you feel is best.

I would prefer to split it up into a different endpoint for each table. I think it makes it easier to understand and test.

EDIT:

I see you tagged your question with REST. In order to be RESTful, you NEED to split it by resource.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a bad practice, you need to have a method for each table considering the data you return as resources, each resource has its own URL, and actions, this is called ReST web services convention, please read the following wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and try to follow the guide lines.
in code it is better to separate the resource actions too as methods this is how you organize readable clean and atomic code functionality.